# SQLServer 2008: Showing the Information with Money DataType in Classic ASP

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic, sqldatatypes, dataformat

I am using MS SQL 2008 to develop one system with Classic ASP.

I want to show 3 Decimal Places the field Datatype is money. I got answer from this http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/moneyformat/ .

I use like this in my SQL Statement :

```
        CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(Sell_Price AS Decimal(19, 3))) AS Unit_Price
```

What I want to know is: Is there more effective way(in performance and usage) than my current one? If there is, please show me. Thanks in advance!

Regards,

RedsDevils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd consider returning the value as-is unformatted from the database and formatting it for display in the UI instead - leave the formatting up to the front end. After all, the db doesn't know for what use the data it returns is being used for - e.g. something else that runs the query may want the full accuracy returned so would save having multiple different versions.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I forgot to mention my webpage is to print and I use view there, from the print bridge form I just send record Id. Then I select from view. So How can I format in HTML? Print form is simple HTML.

Comment: Presumably, the query is being run from classic ASP which then iterates round the recordset, writing the data out to the client - so in that loop, you'd format the value from that column before writing it out. e.g. something like (bit rusty with classic ASP!):Response.Write(FormatNumber(rs.Fields("Unit_Price"), 2))